# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f\left(x^2+f(y)\right)=y+f(x)^2$.

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions of defined on the set of all real numbers with real values, such that
> $$ f\left(x^2+f(y)\right) = y + f(x)^2 $$

**My attempt:**
Putting $x = 0$, $f\big(f(y)\big) = y + f^2(0)$ and putting $y = 0$, $f\left(x^2 + f(0)\right) = f(x)^2$.

But I can't go any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is such that $f(a)=0$ (we know there is such $a$, it is enough to consider $y=-f(x)^2$ for some $x$), then substituting $x=a$ and $y=a$, we have $$f(a^2)=a.$$
Then, set $x=0$ and $y=a^2$, to obtain $$0=f(f(a^2))=a^2+f(0)^2.$$
Since we are only dealing with real numbers, it means that $f(0)=0$, and no other number has $0$ as image.

As consequences, we have $f(f(y))=y$ and $f(y^2)=f(y)^2$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

This shows $f$ is a bijection. Now plug $y=f^{-1}(\zeta)$, we see
$$f(x^2+\zeta)=f^{-1}(\zeta)+(f(x))^2\geq f^{-1}(\zeta)=f(\zeta)$$
Hence $f$ is monotone increasing. Now suppose for some $x_0$ we have $f(x_0)> x_0$, then $x_0=f(f(x_0))\geq f(x_0)> x_0$, a contradiction. Thus we have $f(x)\leq x$. Similarly we have $f(x)\geq x$, so $f(x)=x$ is the only solution.

Comment: $f(f(y)) = y$, so $f \circ f$ is a bijection, hence $f$ is a bijection.